# Comparing multiple columns within same file

Tags: perl, awk

I have to compare two columns col1 and col2 such that if A is occurring
with B and again the same pair is occurring as B followed by A, it should 
print only one pair with all the following columns

```
Input file:
A   B   13.2    0.24    posx    209 215 posy    145 155
B   A   13.2    0.24    posy    145 155 posx    209 215
A   D   19.4    0.28    posx    209 215 posz    366 368


Required output:
A   B   13.2    0.24    posx    209 215 posy    145 155
A   D   19.4    0.28    posx    209 215 posz    366 368
```

input file is very huge (~10gb).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes first two values from each line and forms sorted key which is used to filter out the duplicates,

```
perl -ane '@k = sort @F[0,1]; $s{"@k"}++ or print' file
```

output

```
A   B   13.2    0.24    posx    209 215 posy    145 155
A   D   19.4    0.28    posx    209 215 posz    366 368
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way using `awk`:

```
awk '!(a[$1,$2]++ || a[$2,$1]++)' file
A   B   13.2    0.24    posx    209 215 posy    145 155
A   D   19.4    0.28    posx    209 215 posz    366 368
```

We keep track of column 1 and column 2 by using them as keys to our array `a`. `++` increments the value of our keys whenever they are encountered. `||` is a short circuit operator which only gets triggered for second condition if the first condition is false.

We negate the output of our condition by using `!`. Since `awk` default behavior is to print the line on truth we use that to avoid explicit `print` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '!a[$1,$2];{a[$2,$1]++}' file      
A   B   13.2    0.24    posx    209 215 posy    145 155
A   D   19.4    0.28    posx    209 215 posz    366 368
```

Normally `a` would be named `seen` but I'm partially playing golf with @jaypal's answer so need to keep my strokes down :-).

The important difference between the 2 answers lies in how they'd treat a second line that starts with the same 2 key values as a previous line. jaypals answer excludes lines that match a previously seen $1 and $2 in any order so it would remove duplicates whereas mine strictly adheres to the posted question and only removes subsequent lines that have previously seen keys in the reverse (i.e. current $1 $2 = previous $2 $1).

To enhance the above to exclude duplicates would be (as an alternative):

```
$ awk '!a[$1,$2]++;{a[$2,$1]++}' file
```

Chances are there's never duplicates in the input anyway so it probably doesn't matter either way.